# The GridView 'OrdersGridView' fired event RowDeleting which wasn't handled

Tags: c#, gridview

I’m getting this error over and over again.

Loading the data into the GridView works, but when I want to delete a row I'm getting that error.

```
<asp:GridView ID="OrdersGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" onrowdeleted="OrdersGridView_RowDeleted">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenField1" Value='<%#Eval("oid")%>'></asp:HiddenField>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="titel" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="oid" HeaderText="Itemno" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="prijs" HeaderText="Price" />
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" CausesValidation="false" HeaderText="Update" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="prijs" HeaderText="Subtotal" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

C# codebehind - I'm not really deleting the row from the database but it's a test:

```
protected void OrdersGridView_RowDeleted(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception != null)
    {
        lblStatus.Text = e.Exception.ToString();
    }
    else 
    {
        string sValue = ((HiddenField)OrdersGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[1].FindControl("HiddenField1")).Value;
        lblStatus.Text = sValue;
    }
}
```

But after clicking, I get a bigass yellow page with the next error:

> The GridView 'OrdersGridView' fired event RowDeleting which wasn't handled.

Answer (score 13):

Having a Delete button, or even a regular button in a GridView with a CommandName of delete, will automatically try to fire OnRowDeleting. You can just add it in to make things happy, but don't have it do anything so it doesn't affect the behavior of your delete.

You could add OnRowDeleting to your GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="OrdersGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" onrowdeleted="OrdersGridView_RowDeleted" OnRowDeleting="OrdersGridView_RowDeleting">
```

And then in your CodeBehind add:

```
void OrdersGridView_RowDeleting (object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: wow, microsoft lol. I've been searching for hours, can't beleive there's a behavior like that in 4.5. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

change your row command name from delete to any other like deleterecord

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are handling the "onrowdeleted" event, not the "RowDeleting" event

in your markup, change:
onrowdeleted="OrdersGridView_RowDeleted"

to 
RowDeleting="OrdersGridView_RowDeleting"

Look a the docs for this event: you will also see that your handler's signature will need to change:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowdeleting.aspx
your new handler will look someting like this:

```
 protected void OrdersGridView_RowDeleting(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs e) { 
 if (e.Exception != null) { 
    lblStatus.Text = e.Exception.ToString(); 
   } 
   else 
   {
    string sValue = ((HiddenField)OrdersGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[1].FindControl("HiddenField1")).Value; lblStatus.Text = sValue; 
    } 
 }
```

the RowDeleting event happens, then the onrowdeleted event. The RowDeleting probally lets you Cancel the event.

Comment: I've changed it but it didnt work, I got the same error 

But I had the RowDeleting="OrdersGridView_RowDeleting" AND the RowDeleted="OrdersGridView_RowDeleted" at first and after reading about rowdeleting , I skipped that one cause I dont want to ask the user if he/she is okay with deleting the row, I just want to delete it.

Comment: The Grid View binds to data, and allows someone to delete a record: This event lets you tell the grid what *how* to do that. 

This error is saying "you have asked me to delete a record, but you have not told me how."

the RowDeleted is slated after the delete happens.

Can you indicate how it did not work (same error, different error, lblStatus.Text or sValue  did not have the expected value)? thanks

Comment: its the same error on the same yellow colored error page , the error doesnt even show on my lblstatus label. Coould it somehow have something to do with me publishing the altered files to my host. I dont have the error on my local space.

Comment: The error does not happen locally? That is odd. does it behave as expected locally?.

My first thought would be to check that both the aspx and the dlls have been published properly.

Comment: I only upload the aspx and the aspx.cs file, I didnt create dlls ... yet

Comment: If your aspx file use Inherits=<PageclassName> you need to deploy the dll for this fix to be fully deployed.

Comment: and uploading the Inherits=<.aspx.cs>  is not enough ?
I dont have individual .cs class files only aspx.cs files

Comment: I see you are using dynamic compilation. (you have a App_Code folder and changes to your code behind files do not require a rebuild locally). If this is the case, a dll change is not required. I am not sure why you would see a diff locally and when you push this to a server.